# Linear fit with a previously known slope

Tags: r, linear-regression, weighted

I'm trying to fit a linear function for whom I know the slope to this data in R:

```
> flN
   eCenter      eLow     eHigh     arrivalTime_4_8 timeError_4_8  vCenter     vLow    vHigh
1  56.4997  60.25967  52.73972 2012-05-17 02:01:44      41.01283 2.298964 2.236939 2.367869
2 105.5787 108.02476 103.13254 2012-05-17 01:57:37      27.06803 1.787009 1.771748 1.802860
3 164.0613 166.50385 161.61884 2012-05-17 01:49:47      60.42015 1.530334 1.522997 1.537860
4 226.9886 229.78374 224.19346 2012-05-17 01:49:20      50.83871 1.386016 1.381233 1.390904
```

My Y is `arrivalTime_4_8` and the error in Y is `timeError_4_8`.
My X is `vCenter` and the error `vHigh` and `vLow` for the upper and lower values.

So, have 3 problems about this (I'll put them in order of importance):

1 - How do I fit a linear function with a set slope? I tried to use `lm`, but I can't find a way to put the slope there:

```
lm(formula = arrivalTime_4_8 ~ vCenter, data = flN)
```

2 - I know I must use weights = 1/sqrt(error) to get a weighted fit, but how do I do that with a timeframe axis?

3 - How do I calculate the weights to use if I have the error measurements in 2 axis? A simple squared sum?

```
> dput(flN)
structure(list(eCenter = c(56.4996953402131, 105.578651367445, 
164.061343347697, 226.988601498086), eLow = c(60.2596687117468, 
108.024759195324, 166.503850666149, 229.78374170578), eHigh = c(52.7397219686794, 
103.132543539565, 161.618836029245, 224.193461290392), arrivalTime_4_8 = structure(c(1337216504.88343, 
1337216257.43636, 1337215787.45439, 1337215760.18075), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), timeError_4_8 = c(41.0128309582924, 27.0680250428967, 
60.4201539087451, 50.8387114506802), vCenter = c(2.29896400265163, 
1.78700866407098, 1.53033400915538, 1.38601563560752), vLow = c(2.23693860876912, 
1.77174836673712, 1.52299693760316, 1.38123278889559), vHigh = c(2.36786898717605, 
1.80286021104626, 1.5378599964982, 1.39090403398638)), .Names = c("eCenter", 
"eLow", "eHigh", "arrivalTime_4_8", "timeError_4_8", "vCenter", 
"vLow", "vHigh"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please clarify: (1) are you just trying to estimate the intercept (and its uncertainty), given that you know the slope? (2) can you clarify this question?  I don't understand ... (3) errors-in-measurements models are a little bit complicated and probably can't be easily fitted with `lm`.

Comment: 1 - Exactly, just the uncertainty of the fit and the intercept. 2 - More simply put, how do you estimate errors for an axis with times (do I have to convert everything to seconds for instance or does R do that automatically). 3 - I know how to use the error for fitting in just one axis (for instance if only the Y axis had error I would just give an weight vector to lm equal to 1/sqrt(error)), I'm not sure how to do it for errors in both axis tough.

Comment: can you please post the results of `dput(flN)` in order to make it a little easier to answer the question (i.e. make it reproducible)? I believe R will convert the dates to seconds automatically.  Again, dealing with errors in X is non-trivial.

Comment: what is your pre-determined slope, and what are its units?  Where do you want the intercept (zero point on the time axis) to be (beginning of the time period, mean time, median time, midpoint of the time interval ...)?  By default the origin (see `?as.POSIXct`) is Jan 1 1970 ...

Comment: Predefined slope is: 600.7472 and I'm using it to plot a line trough one of the points with `lineFuncion_trad <- function(x,y0_trad,m) {y0_trad +m*x}` where `trad = "2012-05-17 01:25:41 WEST"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to @jbssm comment, @BenBolker solution seems to give very reasonable results:

```
vCenter_slope <- 600.7472
flN <- transform(flN,w=1/as.numeric(timeError_4_8)^2)
# slope fixed
m1 <- lm(as.numeric(arrivalTime_4_8) ~ 1 + offset(vCenter*vCenter_slope), data = flN, weights=w)
# slope chosen by lm(...)
m0 <- lm(as.numeric(arrivalTime_4_8) ~ vCenter, data=flN, weights=w)

library(ggplot2)
ggp <- ggplot(flN)
ggp <- ggp + geom_point(aes(x=vCenter,y=arrivalTime_4_8))
ggp <- ggp + geom_errorbar(aes(x=vCenter, ymin=arrivalTime_4_8-timeError_4_8,ymax=arrivalTime_4_8+timeError_4_8),width=0)
ggp <- ggp + geom_errorbarh(aes(x=vCenter, y=arrivalTime_4_8, xmax=vHigh, xmin=vLow),height=0)
ggp <- ggp + geom_abline(slope=600.7472, intercept=coef(m1)[1])
ggp <- ggp + geom_abline(slope=coef(m0)[2], intercept=coef(m0)[1],color="red")
ggp
```

[image]

The red line allows `lm(...)` to set the slope, the black line uses fixed slope. Note that the black line is further away from the first two `vCenter` points than you might expect, because you're weighting inversely to error in `vCenter`. If this is your whole dataset, then using weights is highly questionable.

Finally, you can read up on "errors-in-variables" models [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) and [here](http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Graham.Dunn/MSc%20Biostatistics/Linear%20Regression%20with%20errors.pdf). After reading these, you might want to look at the [MethComp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MethComp/MethComp.pdf) package, which supports `Deming Regression' (one type of errors-in-variables regression).

Comment: nice answer.  I think the comment may have been added before I extended my answer to show how to convert the coefficient back to a `POSIXt` object ...

Comment: PS the graph shows that even if you make the error bars +/- 1.96*SE or +/- 2*SE (which I would recommend), there appears to be an inconsistency between the current set of data and the previously established slope ...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a known slope `vCenter_slope` you can use an offset:

```
vCenter_slope <- 600.7472
flN <- transform(flN,w=1/as.numeric(timeError_4_8)^2)
m1 <- lm(as.numeric(arrivalTime_4_8) ~ 1 + offset(vCenter*vCenter_slope),
           data = flN, weights=w)
as.POSIXct(coef(m1),origin="1970-01-01")
## "2012-05-16 20:37:05 EDT"
```

It turns out you do have to convert to numeric if you want to use weights. The weights should be inverse-*variance* weights, I think, not inverse-SE weights.  I don't know whether `timeError_4_8` represents SE or variance here, I'm assuming SE.

As for errors in the X variable -- if you want to deal with this properly you will have to look into measurement-error models, which is a big subject.  On the other hand, if all you want from the model is *prediction* (and not estimation ofthe true slope or correlation), then you can ignore the errors in X.

Comment: I tried this but what I'm getting makes no sense. Something to do with using a time axis perhaps?